# Touchpad scroll not working on Acer Aspire One

Tags: acer, mouse-scroll, trackpad, aspire-one

I just installed Ubuntu Netbook Version 10.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire One and it works perfectly, but For some reason I'm not allowed to use the little scrollpad at the side of the trackpad to scroll like I would on Windows. I checked the settings and it appears to be enabled there, so do I need to install any extra drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you are experiencing, this bug: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/549727

Try this open a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Then if it works please create a file "/etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf" and put "options psmouse proto=imps" in it, so, type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf
```

put the row:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

into the file, save and close, then reboot to test if it works...

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
/etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf
options psmouse proto=imps
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf


options psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: An explanation of what the commands do and how to enter them would be helpful.